# i want my function braces autocomplete in c sharp using visual studio

Tags: c#, braces

I want my function parentheses auto complete in c# using visual studio. I have tried brace completer extension for visual studio but it only complete the curly braces. And also tried productivity power tool , but was not able to find this functionality. Please reply how to do it. I want my pre-defined function parentheses autocomplete when I select a function from a list of available functions , just like netbeans.

Answer (score 2):

VS2013 comes with this option, VS2010 requires visual studio power tools.